# How to restrict an SSH tunnel to a certain outbound IP address on an SSH server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I hope I'm phrasing this question correctly. I have a SSH server that I use for testing that has 2 internet connections running on it. The LAN connection is always on, but the USB connection is on intermittently. Is it possible to restrict the tunnel so that it only ever uses the IP address of the USB connection to browse the internet?

This is what I'm currently using:

```
ssh -v -D 3456 root@mysshserver.net;
```

This is great, but it doesn't tell me if the server's secondary USB connection changes. As I know the IP (for arguments sake 199.90.09.78) of the USB connection, I was hoping I could restrict the tunnel to only using the USB and breaking if the USB went down. I've been playing around with the following:

```
ssh -v -D *:3456 -R *:3456:199.90.09.78:80 root@mysshserver.net;
```

But I think I'm using -R wrong. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: SSH won't be able to manage the network juggling on it's own. Maybe a better solution is to tackle the USB network connection drop by  running a script to reinitialize it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Looking for something more seamless than just a restarter, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a ssh option that can accomplish this, it seems like a routing problem. You would like to route all traffic of the SSH daemon over the USB connection as a policy. Policy routing allows you to route packets over different paths, in your case over the USB connection. You will need `ip` to set the policy and `iptables` to mark packets for that policy.

An (untested) example that routes all traffic over the interface with gateway `10.1.2.3`:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner yourusername -j MARK --set-mark 2
ip rule add fwmark 2 table 3
ip route add default via 10.1.2.3 table 3
ip route flush cache
```

All packets from user `yourusername` will be marked with ID `2`. Then, a rule states that this mark `2` must follow routing table `3` which takes packets to gateway `10.1.2.3`. Finally, the route cache is cleared such that the new route is picked up (if the route was calculated before).

This assumes that the SSH user `yourusername` is only used for the SOCKS tunnel and that you connect to it through the USB connection.

Comment: I will try this now...

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that the SSH server is a Mac. Not sure if they have iptables, but perhaps this would work: http://serverfault.com/a/105736/73641 ?

Comment: @jnthnclrk Hmm, I do not think that there is a one-to-one mapping for these firewall/mark things. However, the keyword that you are looking for is *policy routing*. Perhaps you can even restrict it to a single program.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll take this request over to the Server Fault or Super User site.